# How to download ubuntu container image from Canonical Partner Images website

Tags: docker, container

I am new to Ubuntu/Linux.

I am shifting to Ubuntu because of development problems in Win10 environment.

I have installed docker.

I wanted to run Linux containers on Windows and visited the website:

https://partner-images.canonical.com/hyper-v/linux-containers/?_ga=2.49781606.1556356457.1633112801-1775785339.1633112801

There is no download button. How to download Images of Ubuntu for Linux containers ?

Help is requested.

Dr. Sai

Comment: Click on the folder labeled bionic and keep going through the folders until you find the image you want.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, on Windows OS you could not create a Linux container directly and on Linux OS same you could not create a windows based container on Linux. Because both systems are based on the different kernels, so there is some alternate way for creating the container on a different base kernel system, like you have to create VM for that base system first and then you have to create the containers based on Linux & Windows.